# Проблема с import React from 'react';

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, reactjs, asp.net-mvc

у меня есть employee.jsx которых отображает employee и все окей но как только я добавляю `export default Employees` для того что бы класс использовать в другом месте, на вьюшке ничего не отображается и когда добавляю `import React from 'react'` тоже все ломается

```
 import React from 'react';

class Employee extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: props.employee };
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>
            <table border="2" width="600">
            <tr>
                <td>{this.state.data.Id}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.Name}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.Surname}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.SecondName}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.Age}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.Position}</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>);
    }
}

class Employees extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { employees: [] };
    }

    loadData() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("get", this.props.getUrl, true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            this.setState({ employees: data });
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.employees.map(function (employee) {

                        return <Employee employee={employee} />
                    })
                }
            </div>);
        }
}
function App() {
    return (<Employees getUrl="/employee/getAll" />);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));

export default Employees;
```

Comment: Вынесите хотя бы `App` отсюда в индексный файл, который лежит в корне (в каталоге `src`). У Вас не хватает импорта `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`. Разделите классы `Employee` и `Employees` на два разных файла, возьмите для себя за правило "один класс - один файл" и в каждом файле делайте экспорты своих классов. В класс `Employees` добавьте импорт `Employee` и будет Вам счастье.

Answer (score 0):

1 фаил это один компонент, вынести в другой и сделать экспорт, и все будет работать

Comment: я попробовал, дело не в этом наверное у меня когда подключаю import react from 'react' то ошибка syntaxerror unexpected identifier

Comment: @Kioshilol у вас в примере есть импорт, это с ним проблема?

Comment: да, есть, да проблема с ним

Comment: @Kioshilol вы без этого импорта не смогли бы пользователя реакт компонентом, как у вас все может быть нормально без export если вы не делаете импорт реакт?

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста на мой пример он у меня сейчас не работает но если я уберу первую строчку import React from 'react' и последнюю export default Employees - тогда работает

Comment: @Kioshilol вынести эти два комплекта в разные файлы и подключить один в другой и будет всё работать!

Comment: сделал не получилось.

Comment: @Kioshilol тогда ошибка не в том что вы написали, нужно смотреть в консоль на что ругаться реакт и исправлять...

Comment: я написал на что ругается реакт

Comment: @Kioshilol если быть чуть-чуть внимательнее то можно увидеть что в консоль все написано, как исправить, где ошибка, на какой строчке и так далее... Открой консоль и смотри, нет, значит копируй все что там и Гугл в помощь, то что ты написал это ошибка в синтаксисе...